# HDFS and linux file size

Tags: linux, hdfs

I have a file in hdfs and the contents of the file is just a single number 3 and the size of the file is 2bytes. it should be 1 byte right. I tried files with 5 numbers and it shows 6bytes. Its the same info in the linux as well command "ls -l"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have a newline character on the end of the file.

Use `hexdump -C <filename>` if you want to see exactly what's in the file.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The first column is the offset into the file, starting at 0000000.  Then it shows the content of the file: the character 3, followed by a newline.  Then it shows the offset 0000002, because that's where the file ends.